# Win7 Host and Ubuntu Server on Virtualbox guest port forwarding issue

Tags: django, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04, portforwarding

I'm trying to set up what I believe to be a rather common Django development server configuration, but I'm having issues with the port-forwarding between the guest OS and the host OS.

I'm running:

- Win7 Host
- VirtualBox 4.1.2
- Ubuntu Server 11.04 Guest.

I'm connecting to the VirtualBox with NAT and using the built-in VirtualBox Port Forwarding functionality (from the guest's Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding menu) such that my .vbox XML contains the following section:

```
<NAT>
        <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
        <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        <Forwarding name="guestdjango" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.2" hostport="9080" guestport="8080"/>
        <Forwarding name="guesthttp" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.2" hostport="8080" guestport="80"/>
        <Forwarding name="guestssh" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.2" hostport="2222" guestport="22"/>
</NAT>
```

From the host, I can SSH/SFTP into the guest on port 2222, I can see the nginx "Welcome to nginx!" at 127.0.0.2:8080.

After verifying these, I set up Django and run the Django runsever:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
```

With Lynx from the guest, I get the "Congratulations" Django page at 127.0.0.1:8080.

*However*, when I navigate to 127.0.0.2:9080 from the host, I get "The connection was reset."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not completely sure how it works with port forwarding, but normally to expose the runserver to the external network you need to bind it to something other than localhost - ie run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`. See if that works.

Comment: This was exactly it. I figured it out just after posting, but forgot to come back here and edit. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/): "Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled)."

Comment: Thank you. It's works for me. My guest OS retrieve new IP address, and I can access to my host OS by: http://192.128.1.5:8000 (where 192.168.1.5 - IP of my host OS).

Comment: Daniel, this is exactly the reason it didn't work for me. Nice catch!