# How to properly open Port 8888 in Ubuntu under VirtualBox?

Tags: python, virtualbox

I am working on a Python Flask application in Ubuntu under VirtualBox, run from OSX. Now I want to connect my python application from OSX (the host OS). I am using a NAT networking, and already read about Port Forwarding (which I think it's very easy). But, somehow if I test my application using Google Chrome, try to open `http://localhost:8888` (my server in Ubuntu listen to port 8888), chrome return with `Server return no response` (or kinda)

I have issue the following command in OSX terminal : `VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS" --natpf1 "fikrposdc,tcp,,8888,,8888". And my python application already listening to port 8888, :

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

I've read that in Ubuntu, by default there is no firewall. So, I try to netstat, but issuing `netstat | grep LISTEN didn't gave any output...

Is there something that I missed?

`

Comment: are you trying to access the server FROM chrome on OSX? if so it should be `ip.of.your.vbox:8888`, not `localhost`.  Is your flask app running?

Comment: Hi, I just solved my problem. The Flask app is running.Using NAT networking + port forwarding, I can use `localhost:888` in chrome. VirtualBox will forward it to my guest OS. Using the IP method, seems to work if I use bridged networking. But somehow I can't use bridge networking. It's another issue, that is, I got to reinstall VirtualBox in OSX if I want to use Bridge networking. Which is totally unacceptable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wooops!

Having read related question, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374557/win7-host-and-ubuntu-server-on-virtualbox-guest-port-forwarding-issue?rq=1) with the exact same problem. And I modify my code to run the application :

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)
```

Now I can continue my work!

Thanks